# Link to a file in a MessageBox VC++2008 Windows xp

Tags: windows, visual-c++, hyperlink, messagebox

after some processing my program shows a messagebox saying you can read a log file to know more about what has been done. I would like to show a link to the file instead the name of it. How is this done?

Thanks a lot

UPDATE:

```
IDD_RESULT_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 228, 58
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "Fax/Modem testing tool"
FONT 8, "Helv", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancelar",IDC_BUTTON1,174,38,50,14
    CONTROL         "<a>SysLink1</a>",IDC_SYSLINK1,"SysLink",WS_TABSTOP,105,22,32,14
END
```

This is the code on the rc file where the syslink control was created.

```
BOOL CALLBACK ResultDlg(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)                  /* manipulador del mensaje */
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hDlg,IDC_SYSLINK1), (LPCSTR)"Visit my web site" );
           return TRUE;
        case WM_COMMAND:        
           EndDialog(hDlg, FALSE);
           return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

This is where use SetWindowText ...

The dialog doesn't show up. If a Syslink control is embedded in the dialog. I'm not using MFC... can this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a button that will invoke Win32 function [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) to open a log file.

Comment: I suppose in this case I can't use a MessageBox but custom dialog.

Comment: No you can. 

`if (MessageBox(0, "Do you want to open log file?", "Confirmation", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDOK) ShellExecute(0, NULL, "c:\\your_log_here.txt", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);`

Comment: Finally I made it your way because it was simpler and easier.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you have two options:

A) Make your own dialog from scratch

B) Use a thread hook (SetWindowsHookEx) and catch the initialization of the MessageBox(), resize it a little bit and add your own controls (XP and later have a [link control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760706%28VS.85%29.aspx) that supports basic html. This control also exists on 2000 but is undocumented and has a different class name)

Comment: So much of Windows programming is like this - step just a little outside the boundaries of what Microsoft provides, and the effort goes up by an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the most direct solution would be to have your own dialog box that looks like a standard message window box and use the link control (referenced by Anders in this thread) in place of the standard static text.

I think this is much saner than the SetWindowHookEx route.

Comment: Is there any way of making this dialog showing the name of the log file... dinamically, I mean, show the log name ... that is not always the same name (it depends on the time of execution)

Comment: should be easy enough just use setwindowtext on the link control to set the text on the control when the dialog starts up (perhaps in response to WM_INITDIALOG)

Comment: some things I noticed from the MS-docs to use syslink you need to 
a) Call InitcommonControlsEx before openign the dialog
b) Operating system must be Windows XP+